# Too much gap between table rows

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, android-tablelayout

Please have a look at the following code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/sStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/aStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/oStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/eStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/dStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/aStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In WVGA 5.1 Screen, this generates the following UI

[image]

As you can see, there is a massive gap between rows. I want to avoid this, so it will look good in all smartphones. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make height & width of `tableRow` as `fill_parent` and height of every `LinearLayout` also as `fill_parent`

Use this data

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/sStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/aStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/oStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/eStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/hStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/dStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/aStr"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Table row's height could be `match_parent` and width could be `0dip`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting android:layout_margin to abit less and let me know if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your using linear layout in vertical and applying weight of 3

Answer (score 0):

In your `TableLayout` Set the height to `wrap_content` and your space will be removed. 
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Also to get the best result of the `android:weight` property set the each layout's `width` to 0dp wherever you have assigned a weight.

Comment: Hi, there is a problem in setting the table height to warp content because the content if table should take the entire space available